# Нахождение координат изображения

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, python-3.6, screenshots

Есть код, который находит совпадение на скриншоте по образцу. Однако, когда я пытаюсь переместить на найденный кусочек мышку, указывая x,y, то мышка улетает куда угодно, но не на нужное место..

```
s = pyautogui.screenshot(

    region=(first_screen_click[0],
            first_screen_click[1], 
            width_row,
            height_row))

    n = np.array(s)
    cv_screenshot = cv2.cvtColor(n, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(cv_screenshot, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    res = cv2.matchTemplate(gray_frame, buy_button, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    loc = np.where(res >= 0.8)
    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
        cv2.rectangle(gray_frame, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
```

Перемещаем мышку

```
pyautogui.moveTo(pt[0], pt[1])
```

Собственно вопрос в том, как используя массив от numpy найти эти координаты? То что он присылает никак не совпадет с реальностью..Я даже начертил границу этой командой вокруг найденного совпадения и он отработал правильно. Нужный элемент был выделен.. Помогите пожалуйста, уже весь мозг сломал себе..

```
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
        cv2.rectangle(gray_frame, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
```